# Pascal or Delphi animated images like Gifs

Tags: android, delphi, pascal

I am trying to make a gif animmation in Delphi XE5, but the
 Components library for Android does not contain a Component "TGif image ".
How can put a Animated Images or Gif image in a Form and play it like:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Use HTML? surely there is a browser component?

Comment: At least there is a bad way to do that: you take the single photograms and using a TTimer, you show them.

Answer (score 5):

TImage and TImageControl load GIFs. Neither Android or iOS have native controls for animated GIFs. Animate the images normally (TBitmapListAnimation).

In addition, there is a code [sample on using the web browser component](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/android-code-samples-xe5) for Android.

Alternatively, seek out some third party controls. That's the cool thing about Delphi (and FireMonkey). You can buy functionality.